# Examples of mixture priors on SE-ARD length scale for Gaussian Process models?

Tags: regularization, gaussian-process, hierarchical-bayesian, finite-mixture-model

[Rasmussen and Williams (5.1)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf#page=2) give the following notation for the SE-ARD kernel:

> $\begin{aligned}k(\mathbf{x}_p,\mathbf{x}_q)&=\sigma^2_f\hspace{0.5em} exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x}_p - \mathbf{x}_q)^\top M(\mathbf{x}_p - \mathbf{x}_q) \right)+\sigma^2_n \delta_{pq}\\ M&=\text{diag}(l)^{-2}, \hspace{1em} l \hspace{0.5em} \text{a positive vector}\end{aligned}$

They cite [Neal's 1996 thesis](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/ftp/thesis.pdf#page=134), which in (4.3.1) conjectures about "*informative priors for the hyperparameters associated with the inputs*".

I'm searching for references implementing these "*priors over hyperparameters*":

1. What are some good implementations of $l$ is a mixture?
2. A spike/slab mixture would be consistent with the original goal of ARD, but I'm most interested in approaches where the goal is **clustering over the $l_i$'s**
3. More general references are better, but my immediate application would utilize a logistic or probit link for binary classification.